# how to submit the form data into an array using useReducer hook & i have to get the data and to display it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

how to submit the form data into an array using useReducer hook ?

my main goal is to submit the form data into an array & again i need to get the all of my data (which i have submitted now ) using the same array or different array

here is my action types

```
export const ACTIONS ={
    FETCH_COURSES:"fetch-courses",
    ADD_COURSE:"add-course",
    DELETE_COURSE:"delete-course"
}
```

here i am created a context for this form

here i got the data (here data in an array of objects imported from .js file)
now i need to update the data (which is array of objects) with tha details entered in the form

```
    import { ACTIONS } from '../Reducer/ActionTypes'
    import reducer from '../Reducer/ReducerHook'
    import React, {  createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import data from '../jsonData'
    export const initialState = {
        courses:data,
        singleCourse:{
        name: "",
        type: "",
        image: "",
        duration: "",
        fee: "",
        devoloped:""
        }
    }
    export const courseObj = createContext()
    const CourseContext = ({ children }) => {
    
      const  reducer = (state = initialState,action)=>{
        switch (action.type) {
            case ACTIONS.ADD_COURSE:
                     return {
                         ...state,
                     courses: [...state.courses,action.payload]
                     }
            default: return state
               
        }
        }
    
        const [courses, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
      
        return (
            <courseObj.Provider value={{courses,dispatch}} >
                {children}
            </courseObj.Provider>
        )
    }
    
    export default CourseContext
```

here is my form

```
import React, { useContext, useReducer, useState } from 'react'
import { courseObj, initialState } from '../Context/CourseContext'
import { ACTIONS } from '../Reducer/ActionTypes'
import CoursesList from './CoursesList'

const Courses = () => {
    const {dispatch} = useContext(courseObj)
    const [showHideForm, setShowHideForm] = useState(false)
    const [state, setdispatch] = useReducer((curValues,newValues)=>({...curValues,...newValues}), initialState)
    const {singleCourse} = initialState
    const handleChange = (e) =>{

           const {name ,value} = e.target;
          setdispatch({
            singleCourse :{[name]:value}
          })
   } 


    const toggleForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setShowHideForm(!showHideForm)
    }
    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="text-center mt-4" >
                <button onClick={toggleForm}
                    className={showHideForm ? ' btn btn-danger' : ' btn btn-success'} >
                    {showHideForm ? 'cancel the form' : 'add Course'}
                </button>
            </div>
          {showHideForm &&   <div className="card mt-5 col-12 col-lg-4 login-card p-5  mt-2 mx-auto">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                    <h1 className="text-center mb-5">Add Course</h1>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Course Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name"  value={singleCourse.name}  onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Enter " />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Course Type</label>
                        <input type="text" name="type" value={singleCourse.type}  onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Enter " />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Course Type</label>
                        <input type="text" name="image" value={singleCourse.image}  onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Enter image address" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Duration</label>
                        <input type="text" name="duration" value={singleCourse.duration} onChange={handleChange}  className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Course Fee</label>
                        <input type="number" name="fee" value={singleCourse.fee} onChange={handleChange}  className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Devoloped by</label>
                        <input type="text" name="devoloped" value={singleCourse.devoloped} onChange={handleChange}  className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">submit</button>
                </form>
                <small className="mx-auto text-danger" ></small>
            </div>}

            <div>
                <CoursesList/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Courses
```

ths\e above code is incomplete i stucked there
here is my course form
it contains so many fields i need to add to submit the data into an context api array
the above code is incomplete i stucked there  please any one help me

the form should be submited

Comment: "i got the data from the data object in that data object it contains of object" This is not a clear statement at all. So far I gather that some component dispatches an action of type `ADD_COURSE` and the reducer function adds the payload object to the `state.courses` array. ***BUT*** your question is about submitting a form and adding the form data to your state. Can you update your question to include the component code using this context?

Comment: sorry now i changed that....plz help me regarding that

Comment: Is your `handleChange` callback and `setdispatch` `useReducer` hook/state actually working? That reducer function looks incorrect (see [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dispatch the action with the form field data/state as a payload. In the component it seems the form data is stored in a `state` state variable. Dispatch an action of type `ADD_COURSE` with the `state` as payload.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  dispatch({
    type: ACTIONS.ADD_COURSE,
    payload: state,
  });
}
```